# How to make the menu of WordPress all uppercase display?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to make the menu of WordPress all uppercase display?
I tried to use wp_nav_menu hook, but the parameter of this hook is HTML code, there is no way to convert menu item separately.

The following is my code:

```
function upMenu($are) {
    echo 11;
    var_dump($are); // The parameters that are printed here are the HTML code
    echo 22;
    die;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'upMenu');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to assign a class and Style using CSS

```
  li.uppercase {text-transform: uppercase;}
```

HTML class markup

```
<li class="uppercase">This is my menu</li>
```

Comment: Oh, my God, I forgot to use CSS to solve it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can custom display menu Wordpress with CSS

Go **Appearance** -> **Customize** -> **Additional CSS** and push code here:

```
.header-wrapper .menu li a {
    text-transform: uppercase;}
```